# Setting facts doesn't carry across roles

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use an Ansible playbook to provision an EC2 instance, configure it with Postgres, then provision another EC2 instance and configure a webserver on it with the IP address of the database server.  However, I'm not able to get the role for my webserver to see the address of my Postgres server.  In the database role, I can see that I'm setting a fact and I can display that value with a debug statement, but Ansible errors out when I try to display it in the webserver role.  Here are the artifacts I'm using so far:

main playbook:

```
---
  - name:  provision machines
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    roles:
      - { role: ec2, instance_type: 'm3.large',  application: 'postgres' }

  - name:  provision machines
    hosts: postgres
    sudo: yes
    roles:
      - { role: postgres }

  - name:  provision machines
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    roles:
      - { role: ec2, instance_type: 't2.micro',  application: 'webserver' }

  - name:  Install and configure Engage
    hosts: webserver
    sudo: yes
    roles:
      - { role: webserver }
```

roles/postgres/tasks/main.yml:

```
---
  - debug: msg="{{ hostvars.localhost.ec2.instances[0].private_ip }}"

  - name:  capture Postgres IP address
    set_fact:
      postgres_ip: "{{ hostvars.localhost.ec2.instances[0].private_ip }}" 

  - debug: msg="The postgres IP address is {{ postgres_ip }}"
```

roles/webserver/tasks/main.yml:

```
---
  - debug:  msg="{{ postgres_ip }}"
```

The output shows me that the fact is getting set with the Postgres role"

```
TASK: [postgres | debug msg="The postgres IP address is not-set"] ************* 
ok: [54.174.93.155] => {
    "msg": "The postgres IP address is 172.31.10.196"
}
```

But, in the webserver role, the value is undefined.

```
TASK: [engage | debug msg="{{ postgres_ip }}"] ******************************** 
fatal: [54.172.192.12] => One or more undefined variables: 'postgres_ip' is undefined

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Is this a problem with how/where I'm defining "postgres_ip"?  Or is there a better way to capture a value from one role and use it in another?

Answer (score 0):

My approach has been to add the new host to a new group from the main playbook, and then run a play against that group using roles or other commands from there

For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

#    - create host here
#    - register result as createdhosts

    - name: add host to inventory
      add_host: name={{ item.private_ip }} groups=newinstances
      with_items: createdhosts.instances

- hosts: newinstances

#    - do whatever with those hosts here...
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for - I don't know any way of keeping a variable across multiple plays apart from writing data to a file and then reading it again later (ugly, but also works).